# Is it ok to use 'the' to refer someone's e-mail?

Tags: definite-article

Is it ok to use 'the' when it comes to referencing a person's email?

My understanding is that I shouldn't use 'the' before people's names, but I am referring to the specific person's email.

For example: In regards to 'the' Michael's email, or In regards to Michael's email.

Which one is correct?

Comment: You'd say "Michael's e-mail" or "the e-mail from Michael"

Answer (score 2):

You can use an article, or a possessive, but not both. This applies to "e-mail" and most other nouns.

You could say "The e-mail" or "Michael's e-mail," but you can't say "The Michael's e-mail."

You could also say "The house" or "Michael's house," but not "The Michael's house."

Comment: Thank you so much!